# why .xap file in not displaying in install local apps

Tags: windows-phone, installation, local, sd-card

I'm developing an app for windows phone. But I am facing an issue that my App doesn't displayed after I copy the file into the root folder of SD card.

Comment: Some tweaks with statements to make it little bit easier to understand your situation.

Comment: thnks for reply.. Actually i have developed in app in sencha touch for windows phone. BT when make copy .xap file in the root folder of the SD card.. The .xap file is not exist there .. and when i open windows store and click on the install local apps option. The .xap file is not also not displayed there..